# Importing a Laravel project error with composer update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am trying to use a Laravel framework from git as a simple intranet solution for our company, I am rather new to using Laravel but I was able to get it to work when it comes to creating new projects. The issue happens when I clone the Git repo, https://github.com/sroutier/laravel-enterprise-starter-kit, get it set up with homestead and VirtualBox, and then make the call from `vagrant ssh` in side the specific Code file, `composer update`. I then get this error:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/laravel-5.1-enterprise-starter-kit$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with paUpdating dependencies (including require-dev)         Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 > Problem 1
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.x-dev requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.9 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.8 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.7 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.6 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.5 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.4 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.3 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.2 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.17 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.16 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.15 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.14 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.13 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.12 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.11 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.10 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.1 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.2.0 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.x-dev requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.9 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.8 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.7 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.6 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.5 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.4 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.3 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.21 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.20 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.2 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.19 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.18 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.17 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.16 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.15 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.14 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.13 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.12 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.11 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.10 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.1 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.1.0 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.x-dev requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.8 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.7 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.6 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.5 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.4 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.3 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.2 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.1 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.0-beta.4 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.0-beta.3 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.0-beta.2 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.0-beta.1 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.0-alpha.1 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v5.0.0 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - sroutier/eloquent-ldap 1.0.x-dev requires adldap2/adldap2 5.* -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v5.0.0, v5.0.0-alpha.1, v5.0.0-beta.1, v5.0.0-beta.2, v5.0.0-beta.3, v5.0.0-beta.4, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.x-dev, v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.10, v5.1.11, v5.1.12, v5.1.13, v5.1.14, v5.1.15, v5.1.16, v5.1.17, v5.1.18, v5.1.19, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.21, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9, v5.1.x-dev, v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.2, v5.2.3, v5.2.4, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9, v5.2.x-dev].
    - Installation request for sroutier/eloquent-ldap ^1.0@dev -> satisfiable by sroutier/eloquent-ldap[1.0.x-dev].

 > To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu_bc.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/90-blackfire.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I have tried most different ways to fix it I could find including composer Install and Update workarounds that don't change a thing for my issue. I'm sure its something simple I am just missing but thus far I haven't seen what it could be.

Comment: Well, the error is right there, repeated a hundred times: "the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system". Start googling for "install php extension ldap" or remove the `adldap2/adldap2` package if you don't actually need it. PHP extensions are **not** composer packages, they need to be installed separately.

Comment: Add `ldap` to your vagrant `homestead` configuration file under php modules and do `vagrant reload --provision`